# Возможен ли реактивный маршалинг (marshaling) xml в java-объект?

Tags: java, xml, spring, rxjava2, jaxb

Я делаю запрос на определенный сервис который отдаем мне очень медленно большой xml

Мне нужно не дожидаясь полного ответа документа начать читать и преобразовывать некоторые элементы xml в java-объекты через Jaxb и производить с ними не который операции

Как такое реализовать с помощью reactive spring и возможно ли?

Comment: А нужен ли тебе JAXB вообще? Если файл большой то мб лучше извлекать только то что нужно? А если тебе в этом файле нужно все и именно JAXB, то у меня для тебя плохие новости)

Comment: Привет. JAXB не обязательно можно и другие библиотеки использовать. И да мне не все объекты нужны в этом файле. Хочется чтоб клиент уже видел хоть какие-то результаты по его запросу, а не ждал полной обработки документа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попытался сделать максимально простой пример. Использовал `java 9`.

### Исходные данные:

`Xml` вида:

```
<people count="2">
   <person>
     <name>Jack</name>
     <surname>Green</surname>
   </person>
   <person>
     <name>Ivan</name>
     <surname>Ivanov</surname>
   </person>
</people>
```

Класс в который будет маппится содержимое тега `person`

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
private static class Person {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person{name=%s, surname=%s}", name, surname);
    }
}
```

Теперь нам необходимо написать `publisher` который будет производить анмаршаллинг:

```
private static class MyPublisher extends SubmissionPublisher<Person> {

    void run(String fileName) {
        try {
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
            StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
            xsr.nextTag();
            int count = Integer.parseInt(xsr.getAttributeValue(null, "count"));

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                xsr.nextTag();
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                JAXBElement<Person> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Person.class);
                Person person = jaxbElement.getValue();
                submit(person);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ничего сложного - читаем первый тег, из него получаем значением атрибута `count`. Далее в цикле читаем последующие теги, преобразуем в объекты класса `Person` и отправляем подписчиками

`Subscriber` может выглядить следующим образом:

```
public static class PrintSubscriber implements Flow.Subscriber<Person> {
    private Flow.Subscription subscription;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Flow.Subscription subscription) {
        this.subscription = subscription;
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Person item) {
        System.out.println("Received item: " + item);
        subscription.request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred: " + error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("PrintSubscriber is complete");
    }
}
```

Как заставить все это работать вместе? Очень просто - создаем сначала `publisher`, потом `subscriber` Одного подписываем на другово и запускаем метод `run` для разбора `xml`

```
MyPublisher publisher = new MyPublisher();
publisher.subscribe(new PrintSubscriber());
publisher.run("demo.xml");
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
publisher.close();
```

### Запуск

Как известно в `java 9` ввели модули, работа с `xml` отсутствует в дефолтном модуле `java.base`, поэтому в настройках своего модуля потребуется прописать зависимости. Выглядит это примерно так `module-info.java` :

```
open module ru.izebit {
  requires java.xml;
  requires java.xml.bind;
}
```

**PS** `java.xml.bind` - **deprecated**, но до `java 10` пользоваться еще можно, потом удалят ☹️

Comment: Спасибо. Точно то что нужно, но на совсем в xml много других элементов которые мне нужно пропустить и отбросить а  взять только people элементы

Answer (score 1):

По комментарию могу предложить STAX. Как раз имеет очень хорошую производительность, работает по принципу streaming pull. И уж очень простой буквально 2-3 класса и с десяток методов надо для всей работы. Последовательно извлечешь данные и делай с ними все что хочешь. Так же если в один поток повоображаемой причине не хватит итак хорошей производительности можешь в два сделать работу, одним читаешь данные другим выводи.